# How to get internal attribute from type?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

I have a class:

```
[DefiniteAttribute]
public class SomeClass
{
}
```

Definition of DefiniteAttribute:

```
internal class DefiniteAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

I want to get attribute **DefiniteAttribute** from my class. But I failed, variable **definiteAttribute** is *null*

```
var definiteAttribute = (DefiniteAttribute) typeof(SomeClass).GetCustomAttribute<DefiniteAttribute>(false);
```

Tell me please, how should I write the code in order to get internal attribute from type?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that if I set **inherit** parameter to **true** then internal attribute is returned by method **GetCustomAttribute**

```
var definiteAttribute =  generatedType.GetCustomAttribute<DefiniteAttribute>(inherit: true);
```

Although [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_CustomAttributeExtensions_GetCustomAttribute__1_System_Reflection_MemberInfo_System_Boolean_) only indicates

```
inherit: true to inspect the ancestors of element; otherwise, false.
```